# How to delve into Structuralism?

Tags: postmodernism, derrida, zizek, structuralism

Any recommendations for someone who is interested in reading Structuralist writings and perhaps where to begin?

Comment: See [Structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism) with references and biblio: the "classics" are : Ferdinand de Saussure, Roman Jakobson, Claude Levi-Strauss, Roland Barthes.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps you might want to submit a response so that I may close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mauro points out, you'd want to find the central works of thinkers like Ferdinand de Saussure, Roman Jakobson, Claude Levi-Strauss, and Roland Barthes. The best text around summarizing what they all have in common and the major contributions of this school would be Deleuze's "[How do we Recognize Structuralism?](http://www.topoi.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/How_Do_We_Recognize_Structuralism.pdf)".